# WebView JavaScript only works on Android 8.0 version

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-studio, webview

I have working on a app using WebView on Android Studio, and got stucked on a button to open and close a window (div) with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The problem is: the button function only work well on Android 8.0 version (Genymotion emulator) and i don't know why is this happening, because some other functions are working normaly.

Some sample code:

HTML

Button:

```
<button onclick="open_window()" class="button_template">ABC</div>
```

DIV to open:

```
<div class="window_template" id="window_1">12345</div>
```

CSS Style:

```
.window_template{
    background-image: url(sample.jpg);
    opacity: 0.9;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button_template {
   color: white;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 105%;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;

} 
window_1{
   width: 80%;
   height: 35%;
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function open_window(){
    document.getElementById("window_1").style.display="block";
}
```

Main Activity:

```
package sample.sampla;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings mySettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        mySettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mySettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }
}
```

After all the DIV doens't open.

Comment: Try remote debugger , today it is very easy to do that. Android code is ok but also count on chrome version for 8< . 1) Try to test it on <8 android device. 2) Check mobile chrome version.  My personal suggestion is to try onclick="javascript:YourFunction()" . Android have some diff  like location.assign Works href no ...